# system independent weekday and month names

Tags: r, datetime

Is there a simple way to get weekday and month names in different languages without using the OS locales?

I have a report I want to render in german and english and on linux and windows. There are different locales available on windows and linux or they have different names. So `strptime` and `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)` do not work unless I first check which OS I'm running at.

The package `readr` has this for parsing dates and times I'm looking for something similar for printing.

Comment: How about checking with `.Platform$OS.type` on which platform you are before rendering and set the locale based on the outcome of the check?

Comment: This partially works. I still need to rely on the locale being installed on the System. And it adds a lot of checks.

Comment: I guess for now I'll use the `readr::date_names_lang` function to get the names and then replace numeric values with names manually.

Comment: `date_names_lang("de")` gives you everything you need right? What else do you need which is not present in it?

Answer (score 1):

try the locale settings in some `lubridate`-functions

```
x <- as.POSIXct( "2020-07-10 13:15:45" )
#[1] "2020-07-10 13:15:45 CEST"

lubridate::wday( x, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE, locale="English_United States")
# [1] Friday
# Levels: Sunday < Monday < Tuesday < Wednesday < Thursday < Friday < Saturday
lubridate::wday( x, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE, locale="German_Germany")
# [1] Freitag
# Levels: Sonntag < Montag < Dienstag < Mittwoch < Donnerstag < Freitag < Samstag

lubridate::month( x, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE, locale="English_United States")
# [1] July
# Levels: January < February < March < April < May < June < July < August < September < October < November < December
lubridate::month( x, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE, locale="German_Germany")
# [1] Juli
# Levels: Januar < Februar < März < April < Mai < Juni < Juli < August < September < Oktober < November < Dezember
```

Comment: This also relys on the OS specific locale System, the exact code from your answer causes "Error in Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)" on my system.

Comment: It works; however you have to change locale to locale="en_US" or locale="de_DE"

Answer (score 1):

For now I use this function I wrote myself, I rely on `strftime` for all formatting except the values I want to replace manually. This can easily be extended to locale specific am/pm indicators or custom names or abbreviations.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(lubridate)

my_strftime <- function(t, format, lang){
  
  # replace locale specific formatting with glue template expression
  format_tmp <- format %>%
    str_replace_all("%a", "{a}") %>%
    str_replace_all("%A", "{A}") %>%
    str_replace_all("%b", "{b}") %>%
    str_replace_all("%B", "{B}")
  
  # get replacement values and template with everything except locale specific 
  # weekday and month names
  tmp_data <- list(
    template = strftime(t, format_tmp),
    a        = date_names_lang(lang)$day_ab[wday(t) ],
    A        = date_names_lang(lang)$day   [wday(t) ],
    b        = date_names_lang(lang)$mon_ab[month(t)],
    B        = date_names_lang(lang)$mon   [month(t)]
  )

  # put replacement values into templates
  pmap_chr(tmp_data, function(template, a, A, b, B){
    glue(template)
  })
}

dates <- c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1)

my_strftime(dates, "%a %d. %b %Y", "de")
# [1] "Fr. 10. Juli 2020" "Sa. 11. Juli 2020"
my_strftime(dates, "%a %d. %b %Y", "en")
# [1] "Fri 10. Jul 2020" "Sat 11. Jul 2020"
# > 
my_strftime(dates, "%A %d. %B %Y", "de")
# [1] "Freitag 10. Juli 2020" "Samstag 11. Juli 2020"
my_strftime(dates, "%A %d. %B %Y", "en")
# [1] "Friday 10. July 2020"   "Saturday 11. July 2020"
```